# aws presigned url - validating presigned url gives SignatureDoesNotMatch error

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, pre-signed-url

I've a python script to generate a presigned url and validate it. This script works on my laptop but not on my colleague's laptop. The error message says to check the AWS secret access key and signing method. The AWS access/secret keys is valid and can be used for accessing other AWS APIs. How do I troubleshoot further?

```
import requests
import boto3

url = boto3.client('sts').generate_presigned_url(
    'get_caller_identity',
    Params={},
    ExpiresIn=300)
r = requests.post(url)
print r.status_code
print r.text
```

Error Response:-

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="https://sts.amazonaws.com/doc/2011-06-15/">
  <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.</Message>
  </Error>
</ErrorResponse>
```

Comment: Do both systems have up to date versions of boto3 and botocore?

Comment: `requests.post(url)`... The API reference for the actual service indicates that the `POST` would have a request body. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_GetCallerIdentity.html

Comment: @jarmod - That was it. It looks like the error occurs when the boto3 is at 1.4.7(boto3==1.4.7,botocore==1.7.36). It works fine when boto3 is at 1.4.1(boto3==1.4.1,botocore==1.4.69). Please add it as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine to me.

Do both systems have up to date versions of boto3 and botocore?

Comment: That was it. It looks like the error occurs when the boto3 is at 1.4.7(boto3==1.4.7,botocore==1.7.36). It works fine when boto3 is at 1.4.1(boto3==1.4.1,botocore==1.4.69).